# LDAP server is unavailable exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

I trying to implement LDAP authentication in C# Web Application.

I tried is using the below code.

```
try
{
    using (LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection(this.Server))
    {
        string uname = userName;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.UsernamePrepend))
        {
            uname = string.Concat(this.UsernamePrepend, userName);
        }
        NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(uname, password, null);
        conn.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
        conn.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = (LdapConnection con, X509Certificate cer) => true;
        conn.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
        conn.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
        conn.Bind(cred);
    }
}
catch (LdapException ldapException)
{
    LdapException ex = ldapException;
    if (!ex.ErrorCode.Equals(49))
    {
        this.LogError(ex, userName);
        throw ex;
    }
}
flag = true;
```

Every time I run it, it goes into catch block with exception LDAP server is unavailable.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is `this.Server`? And - just a guess - may this argument be not the correct one or - if it is the server you wanted - is the server currently available?

Comment: Yes.. I pass "localhost:portNumber" there as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `conn.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;` from your code